# NSLocalizedDescription = "The operation couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)"

Tags: core-data

I'm having the following issue:

Setting relationships between elements of the same entity works, but relationships between 2 different entities tend to give the an error. Here is the error output when trying to save:

```
NSLocalizedDescription = "The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)";

NSValidationErrorKey = responsible;

NSValidationErrorObject = "<Actor: 0x8876840> (entity: Actor; id: 0x8875210 <x-coredata://599B45F7-F346-4674-B1B9-5BAEBD575E74/Actor/p2> ; data: {\n    belongings = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a0c660 'belongings'>\";\n    name = Sofie;\n    orderingValue = 2;\n    performsA = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a190d0 'performsA'>\";\n    performsC = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a19110 'performsC'>\";\n    performsI = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a19150 'performsI'>\";\n    performsR = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a19190 'performsR'>\";\n    responsible =     (\n        \"0x8884e10 <x-coredata://599B45F7-F346-4674-B1B9-5BAEBD575E74/Goal/p1>\"\n    );\n    supervisedBy = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a191f0 'supervisedBy'>\";\n    supervising = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a19230 'supervising'>\";\n    type = Person;\n})";

NSValidationErrorValue = "Relationship 'responsible' on managed object (0x8876840) <Actor: 0x8876840> (entity: Actor; id: 0x8875210 <x-coredata://599B45F7-F346-4674-B1B9-5BAEBD575E74/Actor/p2> ; data: {\n    belongings = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a0c660 'belongings'>\";\n    name = Sofie;\n    orderingValue = 2;\n    performsA = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a190d0 'performsA'>\";\n    performsC = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a19110 'performsC'>\";\n    performsI = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a19150 'performsI'>\";\n    performsR = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a19190 'performsR'>\";\n    responsible =     (\n        \"0x8884e10 <x-coredata://599B45F7-F346-4674-B1B9-5BAEBD575E74/Goal/p1>\"\n    );\n    supervisedBy = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a191f0 'supervisedBy'>\";\n    supervising = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a19230 'supervising'>\";\n    type = Person;\n}) with objects {(\n    <NSManagedObject: 0x8885d60> (entity: Goal; id: 0x8884e10 <x-coredata://599B45F7-F346-4674-B1B9-5BAEBD575E74/Goal/p1> ; data: {\n    concerning = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a1ba40 'concerning'>\";\n    conflictedBy = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a1c5c0 'conflictedBy'>\";\n    conflicting = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a1c600 'conflicting'>\";\n    higherLevelGoalAND = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a1c640 'higherLevelGoalAND'>\";\n    higherLevelGoalOR = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a1c680 'higherLevelGoalOR'>\";\n    lowerLevelGoalAND = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a1c6c0 'lowerLevelGoalAND'>\";\n    lowerLevelGoalOR = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a1c700 'lowerLevelGoalOR'>\";\n    name = \"Customer satisfaction\";\n    operationalization = \"<relationship fault: 0x8a1c740 'operationalization'>\";\n    orderingValue = 1;\n    responsibles =     (\n        \"0x8875210 <x-coredata://599B45F7-F346-4674-B1B9-5BAEBD575E74/Actor/p2>\"\n    );\n})\n)}";
```

Here is some of my code:

```
Actor.h

...
@interface Actor (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addResponsibleObject:(Goal *)value;

- (void)removeResponsibleObject:(Goal *)value;

- (void)addResponsible:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)removeResponsible:(NSSet *)values;
...
```

ActorOverview.h

```
...
@interface ActorOverview : NSObject

{

NSMutableArray *allActors;

NSMutableArray *actorFetch;

NSManagedObjectContext *context;

NSManagedObjectModel *model;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *context;
...
-(void)relationshipBetweenActor:(Actor *)a andEntity:(NSManagedObject *)e withInfo:(NSString *)info action:(NSString *)action;
...
```

(relationshipBetweenActor:andEntity:withInfo:action: works fine when setting relationships between 2 actors)

However, it fails when I do the following to set a relationship between a goal and an actor ("An actor is reponsible for a certain goal")

In ActorZoomViewController.m

```
// Define the actor

ActorOverview *ao = [[ActorOverview alloc]init];

Actor *actorInZoom = [ao fetchActorWithOrderingValue:currentActor];



// Define the goal

GoalOverview *go = [[GoalOverview alloc]init];

NSArray *goals = [[GoalOverview defaultOverview]allGoals];

Goal *goalInZoom = [goals objectAtIndex:0];



// Adding a new relationship

[ao relationshipBetweenActor:actorInZoom andEntity:goalInZoom withInfo:@"" action:@"add"];



// Save

[[ActorOverview defaultOverview]saveChanges];
```

Which calls relationshipBetweenActor:andEntity:withInfo:action: in ActorOverview.m

```
-(void)relationshipBetweenActor:(Actor *)a andEntity:(NSManagedObject *)e withInfo:(NSString *)info action:(NSString *)action

{
NSEntityDescription *ed = [e entity];

 if([[ed name] isEqualToString:@"Goal"])

     {

         if([action isEqualToString:@"add"])

         {

             NSLog(@"NEW relationship between Actor: %@ and Goal: %@", [a name], [e name]);

             [a addResponsibleObject:e];            

         }

         if([action isEqualToString:@"remove"])

         {

             NSLog(@"REMOVED relationship between Actor: %@ and Goal: %@", [a name], [e name]);

             [a removeResponsibleObject:e];

         }

     }

}
```

Which results in an error when saving.

Could anyone give me some advice?

Comment: So I found out that my entities are in different contexts:

     Context Actor: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8894b80>
     Context Goal: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x88a5f10>

These contexts are taken care of by ActorOverview and GoalOverview. Anyone who can help me on the right track in order to set a relationship between the two?

Comment: Solved using a combination of following tutorials to change the application to work with a single NSManagedObjectContext:

[Link1](http://mikeahmarani.com/?tag=Tutorial); 
[Link2](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/08/08/add-core-data-to-an-existing-project-in-xcode-4/); 

[Link3](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/06/09/iphone-core-data-tutorial2-add-core-data-to-a-view-based-app/)

Comment: despite none of the links are valid anymore, helped to solve the similar problem. thank you!